# React Native - Tab Navigator issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation with react native and ...clicking on the selected tab in a tab navigator resets the stack inside that particular tab. Please help me get rid of this behaviour.
I only want to go back if the user confirms to go back.

Comment: Please add some of your code to show how you are using react navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest the Tab Navigatior inside a Stack Navigation.

Example:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        TabNavigator: {
            screen: TabNavigator
    }
)
```

There is another solution that will definetely fix this but it will overcomplicate your app so I don't suggest it if you don't have to use it. You can send your navigation props for each navigation(stack and tab in your case).

Example:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(   {
    Screen1: { screen: ({ navigation }) =>
      <StackComponent
        screenProps={{
          stackNavigator: navigation
        }}
      />
    }
})

const TabNavigator = createTabNavigator(   {
    Screen2: { screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) =>
      <TabComponent
        screenProps={{
          tabNavigator: navigation,
          stackNavigator: screenProps.stackNavigator
        }}
      />
    }
})
```

When you do that, you can specifically choose which navigation you want to use. For example: `this.props.screenProps.stackNavigation.navigation.goBack()`.

Comment: Oh alright , i will give it a try . Thank you very much!